# Find first greater element with higher index

Tags: r

I have two vectors, `A` and `B`. For every element in `A` I want to find the index of the first element in `B` that is greater and has higher index. The length of `A` and `B` are the same.

So for vectors:

```
A <- c(10, 5, 3, 4, 7)

B <- c(4, 8, 11, 1, 5)
```

I want a result vector:

```
R <- c(3, 3, 5, 5, NA)
```

Of course I can do it with two loops, but it's very slow, and I don't know how to use apply() in this situation, when the indices matter. My data set has vectors of length 20000, so the speed is really important in this case.

A few bonus questions:

1. What if I have a sequence of numbers (like `seq = 2:10`), and I want to find the first number in `B` that is higher than a+s for every a of A and every s of seq.
2. Like with question 1), but I want to know the first greater, and the first lower value, and create a matrix, which stores which one was first. So for example I have *a of `A`*, and *10 from seq*. I want to find the first value of `B`, which is higher than *a+10*, or lower than *a-10*, and then store it's index and value.

Comment: if efficiency is a concern, you probably want to **not** use nested `apply` loops in this situation, as once you find your value, there is no need to keep searching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sapply(sapply(seq_along(a),function(x) which(b[-seq(x)]>a[x])+x),"[",1)
[1]  3  3  5  5 NA
```

Comment: I have to figure out some tweaks to it, because it eats up way too much memory. I guess there's no real alternative to 'which()', right? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: it has always seemed to me that there should be an option for mapply where you supply A and B but instead of operating piecewise A compares A1 to B1..B2..Bn, then A2 to B2..B3..Bn and so on. Is there a shortcut function like this?

Comment: This should handle your memory issues: `vapply(seq_along(A),function(x) match(TRUE, tail(B,-x) > A[x]), integer(1)) + seq_along(A)` because `match` returns a single index while `which` returns all of them. However, it is a little slower on my machine, I would have guessed otherwise.

Comment: @flodel `1L` is a shortcut for `integer(1)`

Comment: @hadley, `1L` would also work *here*, but `1L` is not the same thing as `integer(1)` and by extension, `2L` is not the same as `integer(2)`, so when it comes to telling `vapply` it should return n integers, I find `integer(n)` more appropriate.

Comment: @flodel doh, skimmed that way too fast - you're totally right, and that what I prefer to use with `vapply` too

Comment: flodel's version works perfectly, and it calculated it for 150000 long vectors in reasonable time. And of course no virtual memory issues with this variant. Thanks everyone for the contribution.

Answer (score 6):

This is a great example of when sapply is less efficient than loops. 
Although the sapply does make the code look neater, you are paying for that neatness with time.

Instead you can wrap a while loop inside a for loop inside a nice, neat function.

Here are benchmarks comparing a nested-apply loop against nested for-while loop (and a mixed apply-while loop, for good measure). *Update: added the `vapply..match..` mentioned in comments. Faster than sapply, but still much slower than while loop.*

#### BENCHMARK:

```
           test elapsed relative
1     for.while   0.069    1.000
2  sapply.while   0.080    1.159
3  vapply.match   0.101    1.464
4 nested.sapply   0.104    1.507
```

Notice you save **a third of your time**;  The savings will likely be larger when you start adding the sequences to A.

---

### For the second part of your question:

If you have this all wrapped up in an nice function, it is easy to add a seq to A

```
# Sample data
A <- c(10, 5, 3, 4, 7, 100, 2)
B <- c(4, 8, 11, 1, 5, 18, 20)

# Sample sequence
S <- seq(1, 12, 3)

# marix with all index values (with names cleaned up)   
indexesOfB <- t(sapply(S, function(s) findIndx(A+s, B)))
dimnames(indexesOfB) <- list(S, A)
```

Lastly, if you want to instead find values of B *less than* A, just swap the operation in the function.
*(You could include an if-clause in the function and use only a single function. I find it more efficient 
to have two separate functions)*

```
findIndx.gt(A, B)   #  [1]  3  3  5  5  6 NA  8 NA NA
findIndx.lt(A, B)   #  [1]  2  4  4 NA  8  7 NA NA NA
```

Then you can wrap it up in one nice pacakge

```
rangeFindIndx(A, B, S)
 #     A   S  indxB.gt indxB.lt
 #    10   1        3        2
 #     5   1        3        4
 #     3   1        5        4
 #     4   1        5       NA
 #     7   1        6       NA
 #   100   1       NA       NA
 #     2   1       NA       NA
 #    10   4        6        4
 #     5   4        3        4
 #   ...
```

---

---

### FUNCTIONS

(Notice they depend on `reshape2`)

```
rangeFindIndx <- function(A, B, S) {
  # For each s in S, and for each a in A,
  # find the first value of B, which is higher than a+s, or lower than a-s

  require(reshape2)

  # Create gt & lt matricies;  add dimnames for melting function
  indexesOfB.gt <- sapply(S, function(s) findIndx.gt(A+s, B))
  indexesOfB.lt <- sapply(S, function(s) findIndx.lt(A-s, B))
  dimnames(indexesOfB.gt) <- dimnames(indexesOfB.gt) <- list(A, S)

  # melt the matricies and combine into one
  gtltMatrix <- cbind(melt(indexesOfB.gt), melt(indexesOfB.lt)$value)

  # clean up their names
  names(gtltMatrix) <- c("A", "S", "indxB.gt", "indxB.lt")

  return(gtltMatrix)
}

findIndx.gt <- function(A, B) {
  lng <- length(A)
  ret <- integer(0)
  b <- NULL
  for (j in seq(lng-1)) {
    i <- j + 1
    while (i <= lng && ((b <- B[[i]]) < A[[j]]) ) {
      i <- i + 1
    }
    ret <- c(ret, ifelse(i<lng, i, NA))
  }
  c(ret, NA)  
}

findIndx.lt <- function(A, B) {
  lng <- length(A)
  ret <- integer(0)
  b <- NULL
  for (j in seq(lng-1)) {
    i <- j + 1
    while (i <= lng && ((b <- B[[i]]) > A[[j]]) ) {   # this line contains the only difference from findIndx.gt
      i <- i + 1
    }
    ret <- c(ret, ifelse(i<lng, i, NA))
  }
  c(ret, NA)  
}
```